# Emberjs. Building a Model with Ember.Object

Tags: ember.js

Forgive me as I am new to Ember. I have, to me , a fairly complex json object that I am working with.

https://gist.github.com/bungdaddy/11152304

My attempt is to build a Model with Ember.Object, use reopenClass for several methods that will return 'sections' of the JSON object that I can use in my handlebars template.

```
var Prequalification = Ember.Object.extend();

Prequalification.reopenClass({
    template: function(){
        return $.getJSON("http://myurl/prequalification")
            .then(function(response){
                var prequalification = [];

                var template = response.collection.template.data

                template.forEach(function(data){
                    prequalification.push(Prequalification.create(data));
                });

                console.log(template);
                return prequalification;
            });
    },
    businessType: function(){
        //Here is where I would like to build a method that will pull from template, the particula JSON that I need and return below.
        return ["Me","Myself","I"];
    }//I wish to further extend from here, other methods that I may need to fulfill model requirements.
});
```

I most likely will need an ArrayController to manage these models. Thing I have read so much, compiled so many different variations that I am quite lost. Any clarity in all this would be a great help to me. I can handle the simple JSON objects, it's the complex models that are kicking my ^&&^$^(*^#

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by 'sections'. Do you want a slice of the array? And so return an array of Prequalification objects. Or do you want to return a JSON object which is a part of a Prequalification object?

Comment: @FlorianParain - sorry unclear. say for example I wanted access to the data node "name":"loanUse" and also its "acceptableValues" Array